# jQuery | add new key value to target.files object

Tags: jquery, ajax, object

I am preparing a form where multiple image upload is allowed. I already prepared the form with success. I loop through the selected images with following code:

```
for (var i = 0, len = e.target.files.length; i < len; i++) {
  // further code here
}
```

I catch and store each selechted image inside the variable _files. Moreover I extend the _file object with the key "path".

*(Since I have different upload sections in my form where images can be selected I would like to extend the _file object with path info to store the images in different folders - i.e. profile picture in one folder; pics for a gallery in another folder.)*

```
for (var i = 0, len = e.target.files.length; i < len; i++) {
  _file = e.target.files[i];
  _file.path = '/path/to/folder/';
}
```

If I log the object _file in my console, I receive following info

```
lastModifiedDate: Thu Sep 15 2016 09:01:53 GMT+0200 (CEST)
name: "image_1.jpg"
path: "/path/to/folder/"
size: 21532
type: "image/jpeg"
```

Everything seems to work so far.

As a last step, I append the _file object into my _formData variable with following line (variable _formData is already initiated before with _formData = new FormData())

```
for (var i = 0, len = e.target.files.length; i < len; i++) {
  _file = e.target.files[i];
  _file.path = '/path/to/folder/';
  _formData.append('file_' + i, _file);
}
```

Than I send the variable _formData via Ajax to a PHP-File. In the PHP-File i use following code to print all the available values in the GLOBAL Var $_FILES:

```
print_r($_FILES)
```

The result in PHP is as follow

```
Array (
  [file_0] => Array
    (
      [name] => image_1.jpg
      [type] => image/jpeg
      [tmp_name] => /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpueAOoX
      [error] => 0
      [size] => 21532
    )
 )
```

All the object values from e.target.files[i] where transferred correctly, but my additionally added path info disapeard.

Now I wonder if that can function at all to extend the object _files?

Thanks for any answers and kind regards
Hansi

Ps: Sorry for spelling errors, English isn't my native language :).

Comment: What you see in $_FILES is not the object that you sent through ajax. It's the file data gathered by php (see: php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php#89674). If you want to use a different path for each image, you've to associate the path with the image uploaded (after all, you can receive more data through POST method).